# SQL to get next not null value in column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

How can I get next not null value in column? I have MSSQL 2012 and table with only one column. Like this:

```
rownum    Orig
------    ----
1         NULL
2         NULL
3         9
4         NULL
5         7
6         4
7         NULL
8         9
```

and I need this data:

```
Rownum    Orig    New
------    ----    ----
1         NULL    9
2         NULL    9
3         9       9
4         NULL    7
5         7       7
6         4       4
7         NULL    5
8         9       5
```

Code to start:

```
declare @t table (rownum int, orig int);
insert into @t values (1,NULL),(2,NULL),(3,9),(4,NULL),(5,7),(6,4),(7,NULL),(8,9);
select rownum, orig from @t;
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One method is to use `outer apply`:

```
select t.*, t2.orig as newval
from @t t outer apply
     (select top 1 t2.*
      from @t t2
      where t2.id >= t.id and t2.orig is not null
      order by t2.id
     ) t2;
```

One way you can do this with window functions (in SQL Server 2012+) is to use a cumulative max on id, in inverse order:

```
select t.*, max(orig) over (partition by nextid) as newval
from (select t.*,
             min(case when orig is not null then id end) over (order by id desc) as nextid
      from @t
     ) t;
```

The subquery gets the value of the next non-`NULL` id.  The outer query then spreads the `orig` value over all the rows with the same id (remember, in a group of rows with the same `nextid`, only one will have a non-`NULL` value for `orig`).

Comment: Great! But your second sample probably contains typos - it doesn't work as expected

Comment: @AlexanderSigachov what do you mean by "probably contains typos"??? The code as posted looks perfectly fine to me. Also, what does "doesn't work as expected" mean?

Comment: it always gets "9" as newval on my data (but outer apply example works as expected)

Comment: @AlexanderSigachov . . . The second method should have used `min()` rather than `max()`.  The `order by` is going in descending rather than ascending order.